# How to change folder view into package view in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, package, java-ee-6

I had a project in Eclipse, but after a refactor > move of a package to another build path, the view of the proyect changed.

**BEFORE**

```
/src/main/java (build path)
com.javalabs.config.beans
  beans.xml
```

**AFTER**

```
/src/main/java (build path)
com
 /javalabs
  /config
   /beans
    /beans.xml
```

How can I switch back the view to package view?

---

Note: I'm already using Project explorer.

It has to be a project corruption, but I don't know how to recover it without creating a brand new one project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Select the Option in Eclipse menu

Eclipse : Window ----> Show view -----> Package Explorer

Comment: Didn't worked. I'm giving 'Selection does not contain a main type', and it does.

Answer (score 0):

**windows -> open perspective -> java browsing (in STS)**